# Не финализируются блоки substrate

Tags: rust, blockchain

Подскажите пожалуйста, у нас есть субстрат нода с консенсусом babe + grandpa. Мы пробовали запускать ее на разных компьютерах и формировать сеть. Все работает если использовать предустановленные аккаунты Alice и Bob. Пытаемся сделать свой конфиг со своими ключами. с помощью subkey сгенерировали 2 пары по 4 ключа. 2 в формате sr25519 (адрес аккаунта и адрес stash аккаунта), затем ключ в формате ed25519(использовали для GrandpaId). Взяли у него seed-phrase и создали sr25519 ключ(для Babe). То есть имеем 2 валидаторов. Запустили ноды и с помощью rpc запросов вставили ключи для обоих валидаторов(babe + gran)

Ноды видят друг друга в сети, создают блоки, но не финалзируют блоки. С чем это может быть связано? На скриншотах конфиг, который мы используем при запуске сети

[image: Фото]

[image: Фото2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл ошибку сам, нужно убрать флаг -tmp перед запуском(данный флаг делает временную базу, где хранятся данные про аккаунты и блоки), создать свои папки командой -d /node/node1 и после вставки ключей перезагрузить ноды